# random movieClips when timer is complete

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I'm making a game in AS3, and I would like to add movieClips randomly on the screen when a a timer is complete.

Exemple :

```
something.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, Finish);

function Finish(event : TimerEvent) : void {
randomly add movieClip1 or movieClip2 or movieClip3
}
```

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much.

---

EDIT

Thank your for your answer. I've tried a lot of things, but nothing really works.. I've tried :

```
_movieClips.push(new _classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * _classes.length)]()); // this line chooses a random index of your _classes Array which will return the Class at that index 
stageRef.addChild(_movieClips[_movieClips.length-1]); 
if (stageRef.getChildByName("_movieClips[0]") == null) { 
trace("poubelle1"); 
_movieClips[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePoubelle, false, 0, true); 
}else if (stageRef.getChildByName("_movieClips[1]") == null) { 
trace("poubelle2"); 
_movieClips[1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePoubelle2, false, 0, true); 
}else if (stageRef.getChildByName("_movieClips[2]") == null) { 
trace("poubelle3"); 
_movieClips[2].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePoubelle3, false, 0, true); 
}
```

No errors, but I can only click if the movieClip just appears. If I'm waiting and a second one appears, I can't click on either one of them.

I've tried :

```
_movieClips.push(new _classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * _classes.length)]()); // this line chooses a random index of your _classes Array which will return the Class at that index 
stageRef.addChild(_movieClips[_movieClips.length-1]); 
if (_movieClips[0].visible== true){ 
trace("poubelle1"); 
_movieClips[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePoubelle, false, 0, true); 
} 
if (_movieClips[1].visible== true){ 
trace("poubelle2"); 
_movieClips[1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePoubelle2, false, 0, true); 
} 
if (_movieClips[2].visible== true){ 
trace("poubelle3"); 
_movieClips[2].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePoubelle3, false, 0, true); 
}
```

But Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
Do you know how I can do that ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You COULD use an Array 'loaded' with Class names:

```
var _classes:Array = new Array(movieClip1, movieClip2, movieClip3);
var _movieClips:Array = new Array(); // this Array is used to instantiate your random MovieClips
```

Then, in your timer finished handler:

```
_movieClips.push(new _classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * _classes.length)]); // this line chooses a random index of your _classes Array which will return the Class at that index
addChild(_movieClips[_movieClips.length-1]);
```

Comment: Sorry but I've got this error : Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor. Do you know why ? (it's for this line : _movieClips.push(new _classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * _classes.length)]);)

Comment: You may need to add a pair of empty brackets () after the second square bracket, ie - at the end of the line:  ... * _classes.length)]());  These would normally be used to pass parameters to your newly instanted Class. The other problem may be with how you're populating your _classes Array. Do not pass in Strings: ie, NOT "movieClip". You want movieClip so that you're passing a Class as opposed to a String-of-the-name-of-the-class. Let me know if that still doesn't work.

Comment: Perfect ! it was the brackets. Thank you !

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to make them clickable ? (cause if I put movieClip1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clciked, false, 0, true); it tells me error 1061 undefined via the reference Static Class

Comment: You're getting that error because you are adding the event listener to the Class, not an instance of that Class. In the code I provided you can refer to the added MovieClips through the _movieClips Array; The most recently added MovieClip will be in the last index position of the Array, which will be the Array's length-1 (the first added MovieClip will be at index position 0). Add your event listeners like; _movieClips[_movieClips.length-1].addEventListener(...) if you want to add it to the most recently added MovieClip. Or use an index position. Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, just as a tip; It's generally a convention that Class names start with a capital letter. That can reduce confusion about what's an instance and what's a Class. So maybe name your MovieClips MovieClip1, MovieClip2, etc (although you might want more descriptive names).

Comment: it works, thank you ! So, if the function is called twice and 2 MovieClips are on stage, one is at index position 0 and the last one added at index position -1. So if I want that when we click on one of the movieclips, it disapear it would be something like this ? : stageRef.removeChild(_movieClips[_movieClips.length-0]); stageRef.removeChild(_movieClips[_movieClips.length-1]); or something like this :  if childAt(0){stageRef.removeChild(_movieClips[_movieClips.length-0]);} if childAt(1)... ??

Comment: Almost, but not quite. You can EITHER refer to your MovieClips by their position in the Array, eg: _movieClips[0].addEventListener... ('0' would be the first MovieClip in the Array, '1' would be the second and so on) OR, if you want to refer to the LAST MovieClip in the Array you can use _movieClips[_movieClips.length-1].addEventListener... But, either way, every time you add a MovieClip, it will be the LAST one added, so if you're adding eventListeners in the function where it is created you can use the second option.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47023/discussion-between-moosefetcher-and-user2421975)

Comment: You're getting an error because you are referring to the .visible property on the second and third MovieClips BEFORE they've been added. Think about what will happen the FIRST time you click. The first MovieClip will be .pushed onto the _movieClips Array. Checking if THAT MovieClip is visible is fine - You are running into trouble when you immediately try to check if _movieClips[1] is visible. After ONE click, it doesn't exist yet! The solution is to JUST add the eventListener to the most recently added MovieClip (_movieClips[_movieClips.length-1]) and check event.target in the event handler

Comment: By the way, you may want to ask this as a separate question or continue as a discussion - we've already had a request to take this to chat.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I've created a new post there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633566/addeventlistener-of-random-movieclips  Thank you