# addEventListener of random MovieClips

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in AS3.

I've got in my code :

```
public var _classes:Array = new Array(poubelle1, poubelle2, poubelle3);
public var _movieClips:Array = new Array();
```

public function apparitionDechet(event : TimerEvent):void{

```
    _movieClips.push(new _classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * _classes.length)]());
    stageRef.addChild(_movieClips[_movieClips.length-1]);
```

I'm trying to put an addEventListener on the MovieClips. 
The player should be able to click on a MovieClip when it's appearing or he can wait. Few will appears, and he can click on them at any moments. 
Each clicks will make the MoviClip disapear..

So I've put :

```
_movieClips[1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePoubelle, false, 0, true); 

}
        public function removePoubelle(e:MouseEvent):void{
            if(e.target=="_movieClips[0]"){
            trace("ok1");   
            }
            if(e.target=="_movieClips[1]"){
            trace("ok2");   
            }
             if(e.target=="_movieClips[2]"){
            trace("ok3");   
            }
```

but it's not that...

Do you know how I can do that ? 
It's my first time that I'm using the randomly apparition of MovieClips...

Thank you very much,

---

EDIT

So I've followed your tips and did this :

```
        public function apparitionDechet(event : TimerEvent):void{


var mc:DisplayObject = new _classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * _classes.length)]();
    _movieClips.push(mc);
    stageRef.addChild(mc);
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePoubelle, false, 0, true);

}
        public function removePoubelle(e:MouseEvent):void{
var mc:DisplayObject = e.target;
            var i:int=_movieClips.indexOf(mc);
if (i>=0){ 
    _movieClips.splice(i,1);
    mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
}

}
```

But I've got the error 1118 Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject

---

EDIT 2

Quick question though, is it possible to do :

```
if(stageRef.contains(poubelle1)) { 
trace("poubelle1détécté"); 
} 
if(stageRef.contains(poubelle2)) { 
trace("poubelle2 détécté"); 
} 
?
```

movieClips poubelle1 and poubelle 2 are defined like this

```
public var _classes:Array = new Array(poubelle1, poubelle2, poubelle3);
public var _movieClips:Array = new Array();
```

it doesn't seem to work if I do that.(error 1027 Contrainte implicite d'une valeur du type Class vers un type sans rapport flash.display:DisplayObject) Any idea why ? 
Do you want me to create a new post ?

Thank you

Comment: By 'but it's not that...' you mean that they are not disappear or you can't see traces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to remove the movieclip that was clicked, you already have it as the event's target. So you get its parent and call `removeChild()`. Don't forget to remove the event listener off the target.

```
public function removePoubelle(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var mc:DisplayObject = e.target as DisplayObject;
    if (!mc) return; // typecast failed
    mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
    // mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePoubelle, false, 0, true); 
    // the line above might not be needed as the listener weakly references the mc
}
```

And you put the listener as soon as you create your new movie clip.

```
public function apparitionDechet(event : TimerEvent):void {
    var mc:DisplayObject = new _classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * _classes.length)]();
    _movieClips.push(mc);
    stageRef.addChild(mc);
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePoubelle, false, 0, true); 
}
```

See, how you can avoid referencing the newly created movie clip without ugly `_movieClips[_movieClips.length-1]` construction? You just make a local variable which is then instantiated for your random MC out of `_classes`, and you then use the variable to do everything else that's needed at the time of creation.

But, this is still not enough - your "poubelle" is still inside your `_movieClips` array, so it'll grow. You need to clean up the array too. So, add this code to `removePoubelle`:

```
var i:int=_movieClips.indexOf(mc);
if (i>=0) _movieClips.splice(i,1);
```

This gets the position of the clicked movie clip inside your array, and if it's a valid one (zero or more) the array is told to remove that element.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the explanations. Very very helpful. But same thing as "moosefetcher", the code doesn't like the e.target line... var mc:DisplayObject = e.target;  (error 1118). Any idea why ?

Comment: Okay, do an explicit typecast. (Fixing post)

Comment: Super thanks ! It works perfectly ! Very useful all this discussion. Thank you.

Comment: Quick question though, is it possible to do : if(stageRef.contains(coco1)) { trace("coco1 détécté"); } ? it doesn't seem to work (error 1027 Contrainte implicite d'une valeur du type Class vers un type sans rapport flash.display:DisplayObject)

Comment: Do you need to check if `coco1` is on stage? In case `coco1` is an instance, you can check `if (coco1.stage) trace("There's coco1 on the stage!");` In case `coco1` is a class, it's not this easy - you need to traverse the displaylist and check if any object `is coco1`, if yes, then trace, if not, then no.

Comment: sorry, I've made a mistake. I meant "poubelle1" (not coco1). Poubelle1 is define like this public var _classes:Array = new Array(poubelle1, poubelle2, poubelle3);

Comment: If so, you have to go the longer way, with iteration. Also, you'd better open one question per problem.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using just _movieClips[1]. That refers specifically to the SECOND object in your _movieClips Array.
You should add your eventListener as soon as the MovieClip is added to the _movieClips Array. You can add it to the most recently '.push'ed MovieClip, like this:

```
_movieClips[_movieClips.length-1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePoubelle);
```

Do that on the next line after the line where MovieClip is pushed into the _movieClips Array.

Your event handler (the removePoubelle function) will be passed a MouseEvent and you can refer to the .target of this event to isolate WHICH MovieClip has been clicked:

```
private function removePoubelle(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var mcToRemove:DisplayObject = e.target;
    removeChild(mcToRemove); // note there is no need to refer to .parent as the MovieClip was added in this Class
    // more code to come - see below
}
```

Also note: Because each MovieClip has an eventListener added WHEN IT IS CREATED, e.target will ALWAYS refer to whichever MovieClip was clicked.

The only other thing you may want to implement is removing the MovieClip from the _movieClips Array. This can be done in the removePoubelle function too:

```
var removalIndex:int = _movieClips.indexOf(MovieClip(e.target)); // here I am 'casting' the e.target to the type MovieClip. That basically just means I'm changing it's type from DisplayObject to MovieClip (which is a subclass of DisplayObject)
if (removalIndex>-1) {
    _movieClips.splice(removalIndex, 1); // this line removes one item at the index returned from the _movieClips.indexOf... line above.
}
```

Let me know if any of this doesn't make sense.
}

Comment: Ok, it makes sense.Thank you for all the explanations. It's clearer now (even if I had to read it twice in order to understand everything). But the code doesn't like the line where e.target is refering to the clickedMovieClip :  var mcToRemove:DisplayObject = e.target; (error 1118 : Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject)  Any idea why it doesn't like it ?

Comment: The problem is that e.target returns an object that's of the type Object. You can 'cast' e.target to a DisplayObject type like this:  var:mcToRemove:DisplayObject = Object(e.target);  This basically 'converts' the Object to a DisplayObject. 'Casting' like this works only because DisplayObject is a SUBclass of Object. You can't cast to Classes that aren't subclasses of the Class you're trying to convert.

Comment: Quick question though, is it possible to do : if(stageRef.contains(coco1)) {
    trace("coco1 détécté");
   } ? it doesn't seem to work (error 1027 Contrainte implicite d'une valeur du type Class vers un type sans rapport flash.display:DisplayObject)

Comment: It depends what 'coco1' IS. The 'contains' method takes a DisplayObject as a parameter. If you don't pass a DisplayObject to it, you'll run into trouble. I'm guessing you actually mean to pass an INSTANCE of the coco1 Class, so you should do that. And, once again, if 'coco1' is a Class, it really should be named with a capital first letter - That will make things much less confusing for you (and others) in the long run.